# ModuleNotFound exception with zipapp and compiled C code

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging, zipapp

I encounter strange behavior using Python's zipapp feature.

Python version: 3.10.5

```bash
# these steps come from the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html
$ mkdir myapp

# this is the library I'd like to use
$ echo "cysystemd==1.5.3" > requirements.txt
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --target myapp

# prepare the zipapp entry point, just import the library
$ echo "from cysystemd import journal" > myapp/__main__.py

# executing the directory works fine. the import takes place and the program terminates successfully.
$ python3 myapp/

# zipapping
$ python -m zipapp -p "python3" myapp 

# now executing again, this time the zipapp:
$ ./myapp.pyz                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samba/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/samba/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/samba/git_wsl/zipapp_experiment/./myapp.pyz/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/samba/git_wsl/zipapp_experiment/./myapp.pyz/cysystemd/journal.py", line 7, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cysystemd._journal'
```

I can't get my head around this import issue. `_journal` refers to a compiled C module which is present in both locations, the `myapp` directory as well as the zipapp `myapp.pyz`:

```
$ find myapp/ | grep journal                                                              
myapp/cysystemd/journal.py
myapp/cysystemd/__pycache__/journal.cpython-310.pyc
myapp/cysystemd/_journal.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

```
$ unzip -l myapp.pyz| grep journal                                                    
     4880  2022-06-21 21:39   cysystemd/journal.py
   301104  2022-07-19 18:47   cysystemd/_journal.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
     5043  2022-07-19 18:47   cysystemd/__pycache__/journal.cpython-310.pyc
```

Any ideas what is wrong here? I suspect an issue related to `sys.path` but I have no idea how to get this fixed in a zipapp archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a limit imposed by Python's import mechanism. Python has various import hooks:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path_hooks
[zipimport.zipimporter,
 <function _frozen_importlib_external.FileFinder.path_hook...]
```

And [zipimport](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html) says:

> Any files may be present in the ZIP archive, **but importers are only invoked for .py and .pyc files. ZIP import of dynamic modules (.pyd, .so) is disallowed**.

To get around that limitation tools in that space (like [pex](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex), [shiv](https://github.com/linkedin/shiv), ...) use the [zipapp](https://peps.python.org/pep-0441/) approach but they will extract the zip file before running it, transparently - hence circumventing the limitation of the zipimport module.

Please have a look at using cysystemd with the [shiv](https://github.com/linkedin/shiv) tool here:

- https://gist.github.com/miku/e0a3d4abb2ba7dbb9ca5f11369fc64f4

---

PS. There's quite a bit of a packaging options; [Python Packaging Authority](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/) has more info on that; some talks on the topic:  ["The Packaging Gradient", PyBay2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLVNWfPWAC8), ["Packaging Python Application", PyCon Balkan 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nqr3C2mIs2U), ...

Comment: Wow. Need to try this tomorrow. Never would have known these details. Tnx alot

Comment: I confirm that this is working. It's interesting to extract the created app.zip and see what `__main__.py`  and the `_bootstrap` package are doing.